# Troubleshooting WS2812B LED strip

Tags: led, ws2812

I am doing a project for my master thesis and I have 6 stripes of [WS2812B](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) LEDs each one containing 77 LEDs. I finished the design and now want to turn them on.

I used an old power supply to power it, but now that I am running it, doesn't work. I checked the voltage with a multimeter and it shows that I have 5 volts and it seems doesn't have any problem but the data doesn't transfer to my strip.

I just copy past FastLED from libraries and changed the number of LEDs. I thought maybe I am using the Funduino from school, maybe this is a problem and I need another Arduino board?

[image: Photo of test]
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Please show us a schematic or wiring diagram on the picture we cannot really see the connections. Have you tried to only connect 1 little strip for testing? And please show us your code (you can add it to your question by editing it. Don't forget to format it correctly by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button of the editor).

Comment: Since, in the photo, you are only testing with a very short strip of 4 leds, I'd suggest try powering the strip from the Arduino's 5V. Just to make sure that the code works. After that you can add the PC power supply.

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 1):

Are you completely sure that these are WS2812B LEDs? To read more, check out this great link from Core Electronics:
https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/addressable-rgb-led-controllers.html

It is more than likely your code. Download the code from a known working example and get that working. Try using an example program such as:

- https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-control-ws2812b-individually-addressable-leds-using-arduino/
- https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/ws2812-addressable-leds-arduino-quickstart-guide.html
- https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/software

Once you have known working hardware then delve into your own code and find the problem.

Also check your wiring with fresh eyes. It could be something simple.